# Join and update same column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables as :

TableA:

```
ID Value
1  A
2  B
```

TableB:

```
   Rank Value
    12   A
    13   B
```

I need to join both tables on *Value* column and update *Value* column of TableB with TableA's ID column. So result TableB will be:

```
Rank Value
12   1
13   2
```

I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: What datatype is `Value` in TableB?

Comment: All column data types are varchar(50)

Answer (score 2):

Use `update` with `join`:

```
update b
set b.value = a.id
from tableb b 
  join tablea a on b.value = a.value
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64901/1)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do this with a `join` in the `update`.  The specific syntax in your case is:

```
update b
    set value = a.id
    from tableb b join
         tablea a
         on b.value = a.value;
```